# enforce typetrait for all subclasses

Tags: c++, type-traits

is there are a way I can check during compile time, that all subclasses of a given class satisfy a given typetrait?

For example: I want to make sure that all classes that inherit from Base are trivially copyable.

```
#include <type_traits>

class Base
{ };

class Foo : Base
{ };

class Bar : Foo
{ };

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Base>::value, "");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*I want to make sure that all classes that inherit from Base are trivially copyable.*" Can you get a list of all class types that inherit from Base?

Comment: maybe [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) can help. However, why do you want to require all subclasses to be trivially copyable?

Comment: Why I need this: I have a legacy code base that uses memcpy to "move" objects.